# Ayuda con Textbox y Forms

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

Hola a todos tengo una pequeña duda supongamos que tengo un form1 padre en el que tengo un textbox y un boton, al hacer clic en el boton me abre mediante un show dialog el form2 donde tengo otro text box y un boton, en el form2 introduzco una cadena y al hacer clic necesito que esta info pase al textbox del form1 que se encuentra abierto. No se como hacerlo soy noob por favor ayudenme

Answer (score 1):

si tienes un botón en donde vas a pasar de un form a otro puedes hacer esto.
 
   (desde el form1)

```
Private Sub Command1_Click(Index As Integer)
    form1.hide
end sub
```

y si tienes dos cuadros de texto en el form 1 y quieres usarlos en el form 2 seria asi.

(desde el form2)

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   form2.text1a.text = form1.text1.text
   form2.text2a.text = form1.text2.text
end sub
```

es decir tienes que hacer primero referencia al formulario de donde quieres obtener los datos y despues el objeto. Espero esto resuelva tu duda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, encontré la respuesta a mi duda en un ejemplo de otra web, pero de corazón te agradezco que te hallas tomado el tiempo en responder ya que nadie mas lo hizo. Saludos :)

Comment: Me Agrada la idea que hayas sacado el tiempo de investigar y hayas llegado a la solución por tu cuenta, eso es de lo mas satisfactorio.
Buen día! :D